# What is the order of dragon difficulty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While playing Skyrim I have noticed that there are different types of dragons and that they are sometimes different colored and use different abilities. What is the order of weakest type of dragon to strongest type of dragon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it is best to cite [this wiki page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons_%28Skyrim%29) here. The common dragon types are:

- *Dragon: Brown-colored dragons; they are the first dragons encountered in Skyrim and are the weakest.*
- *Blood Dragon: Green-colored dragons that have finned crowns and spade-like tails.*
- *Frost Dragon: White and blue, ice-affiliated dragons with black-colored dorsal spines.*
- *Elder Dragon: Bronze-scaled dragons with arrow-shaped tails; second to Ancient Dragons.*
- *Ancient Dragon: Red, black and orange-colored dragons; The most powerful dragon in the base game.*
- *Revered Dragon: Orange-colored dragons introduced in Dawnguard; second most powerful variant.*
- *Legendary Dragon: Black, purple-colored. Maximum level dragon introduced in Dawnguard; most powerful variant.*

There are a couple of other dragons inside the game. Other than some skeletal dragons, that do not drop scales nor yield a soul; their names are Dumehviir the undead dragon, two red dragons Nafaalilargus and Odahviing and the black dragon Alduin. You can look for specifics on them at the wiki pages.

Comment: You can get Normal Dragons that are white.

Comment: Want to mention dragons have 150 magicka they use to shout. This page: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon lists all the generic types of dragons in the game(including those added by Dawnguard and the Serpentine Dragon from the Dragonborn DLC) along with their health, stamina, and their damage output from elemental and melee attacks. Edit: Also includes the level at which you'll encounter each type.